# next.js IIS deployment with custom server, middleware with redirect causes app to break

Tags: node.js, iis, next.js, middleware

I have a next.js app and use a custom server for deployment in IIS.

I use a middleware for https redirect, but when I use it on deployment my app breaks.
It seems to loop through redirects. check the image for details of the error.

[error screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1cni.png)

the middleware I use is a classic middleware:

```
import  { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

type Environment = "production" | "development" | "other";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const headers = new Headers(request.headers);
  
    const currentEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV as Environment;
    const isHttps = headers.get("x-forwarded-proto")?.split(",")[0] === "https";
    const isLocalhost = request.headers.get("host")?.includes("localhost");
  
    if (currentEnv === "production" && !isHttps && !isLocalhost) {
      const newUrl = new URL(`http://${headers.get("host")}` || "");
      newUrl.protocol = "https:";
      return NextResponse.redirect(newUrl.href, 301);
    }
  }
```

does anyone have a suggestion?

I tried different versions of the middleware and also tried to perform the redirect on the custom server, but I always get this error: ../pipe...

Comment: You can directly use url rewrite for redirection in IIS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module#creating-a-redirect-rule.

Comment: Thank you @TengFeiXie for your comment. I have already tried this before and I had the same problem, but your answer made me realize that I had tried this url rewrite as one with the lowest priority..

I made this of the highest priority and it worked!

I followed the instructions on this url if anyone is interested: https://aboutssl.org/iis-redirection-http-to-https/

thank you again